# Python PyQt5 subclassing QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest data duplication

Tags: python, pyqt, webkit, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

During development of a particular system that uses PyQt5, I need to subclass QNetworkAccessManager in order to override createRequest method. I do this in order to save the HTTP resources before the WebView renders them and cleans the buffer(which is a QIODevice).

I'm using peek() so the buffer would not be cleared when it gets to the webview.

However, there are some times where the buffer is not cleared once it gets to the WebView, I have noticed that it happens when content is unsupported by the WebKit/WebView, but also seems to happen at other times.
Since I append the data to my own variable (basing myself on the fact that the buffer is cleared afterwards), this causes data duplication.

For example:

```
<script>hello</script
```

If the data is not cleared, the message I will end up receiving could be:

```
<script<script>hello</script>
```

Or other variations of duplication.

Below is the snippet of the subclass which produces the aforementioned bug.

```py
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager

class NetworkAccessManager(QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

    def createRequest(self, op, req, outgoingData):
        reply = QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self, op, req, outgoingData)

        reply.data = b''

        reply.readyRead.connect(lambda reply=reply: self._on_reply_ready_read(reply))

        return reply

    def _on_reply_ready_read(self, reply):
        if reply.isReadable() and reply.isOpen() and reply.bytesAvailable():
            reply_data = b''
            bytes_available = reply.bytesAvailable()

            # I put this attribute when the QWebFrame unsupportedContent event is fired.
            if hasattr(reply, 'is_unsupported') and reply.is_unsupported:
                # When content is unsupported, webview does not call read. 
                # We call read and clear the buffer instead.
                # This works fine!
                reply_data = bytes(reply.read(bytes_available))
            else:
                # The problem resides here.
                # At certain times the buffer is not cleared, leading to duplication of data.
                reply.data += reply_data
```